# `objectName.key` v/s `this.key` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, oop

I am fairly new in JavaScript and have been learning JS objects.

An object is basically a collection key:value pairs and the value to a key can be a function.

Now, to access some other key within the same object from a function `this` keyword is used.

For example,

```
let user = {
    name : "John",
    greet : function () {
        alert(`hello ${this.name}`)
    }
};
```

So if I go on and run `user.greet()` the output is "hello john".

But if i keep everything in the above code same, except replace the `this` key word with the objectName, like so:

```
let user = {
    name : "John",
    greet : function () {
        alert(`hello ${user.name}`)
    }
};
```

The code still produces the same output.

So my question is what exactly is the advantage of using `this` instead of accessing the property with the object name itself ? And what exactly is the difference between these two?

Comment: `this` changes depending on how the function is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You're assuming there will be only one "user", but most programs use many objects of the same kind (or "class"). This is where `this` comes into a play.

Comment: Learning by doing: Try storing the function in a variable (like `const greeting = user.greet;`) and calling it `greeting()`. Or passing it as a callback `setTimeout(user.greet, 100)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was more concerned with the differences between the two. I sort of have an adequate understanding of how `this` works. Anyways it still helped me so thanks.

Comment: @Thomas It throws a TypeError.